# Store doesn't update fast enough with Elasticsearch delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, flux

A little context: I have a platform where users submit an application to me and I can accept/reject their applications. The list of applications is listed on `Applications.js.coffee`, and each individual application is listed on `Application.js.coffee`.

I have this issue where after I click Delete inside each individual application, it would go back to the list of applications too fast? Since it loads too fast, my `store` isn't fast enough to reprocess the list of applications, and so the application I had deleted still shows up on the list.

```
# Applications.js.coffee
componentDidMount: () ->
    com.stores.applications.on("apps", @onApps)

onApps: () ->
    a = com.stores.applications.list(@state.apps)
    @setState(apps: a)

# Application.js.coffee
onDelete() ->
    com.actions.delete(@props.id).done(() =>
        com.actions.transitionTo("URL back to Applications.js")
```

I'm using Elasticsearch...I actually don't have any experience in this, since I'm collaborating on this project and am not familiar with this technology. I was told to look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html#delete-refresh.

I think I have two options: 1. delay loading the page by a few milliseconds so my `store` call would have enough time to retrieve the new list of applications (with `delay`?) or 2. do something with Elasticsearch which is what I'm asking for help on.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a promise and return it when your db delete is finished https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: He's already doing that. His "promise-like" function uses a `.done()` callback instead of a `.then()` callback. Simply adding a promise does exactly the same thing so it won't help.

Comment: I would need a little more explanation than that if possible. Do I just replace my `.done()` with a `.then()`?